# Read values from gauge with image processing

Tags: image, python-2.7, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to read fluid levels in a column from a photograph I took, to see if I can automate the data collection.

So far, I have been able to use some code, below to identify the outline of where the fluid level is.

[image: original image, cropped]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage
from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import canny
from scipy import misc
from skimage.filters import roberts, sobel, scharr, prewitt
%matplotlib inline

perm = skimage.io.imread('C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\perm2_crop.jpg')
edge_roberts = roberts(perm[:, :, 2])

plt.imshow(edge_roberts, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

[image: edge_roberts]

What I need to figure out now is how to identify the break, and then how to translate that into a data value that I can scale to the values on the column.

Any ideas about what packages or methods I would use to to do this?  Any examples would also be appreciated.

Comment: Can you make life easier for yourself by colouring the water, or changing the lighting, or putting a cross-hatched pattern behind the water...?

Comment: Coloring the water is probably not an option, but lighting, backlighting, or putting a pattern behind the column are potential options.  Assuming I did get an image with more contrast, I'd still need the processing tools to identify the reading as above, though.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd start by rectifying the image, so that the gauge is perfectly vertical.  Then, sum the array across columns, so that you are dealing with a 1-D signal.  There, you can pick up the jump.

Comment: bad start. first you get a good image, then you think about how to process it. your image is of very poor quality. I'm sure you can get better material... crap in = crap out